# HTML email font size in gMail

Tags: html, css, webkit, gmail, html-email

In gMail, the `font-size` that I set for `<td>`s work except for this one: (edit: I spotted the typo, changed it but still doesn't work on gmail :( )

```
   <tr>
      <td class="inner" style="font-family: 'Arial Black', 'Arial Bold', Gadget, sans-serif; font-weight:800; font-size: 80pt!important; text-align: center">
           $33
      </td>
   </tr>
```

Any idea why this doesn't work? Strangely enough, it works for this:

```
<tr>
    <td class="inner" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16pt; text-align: center; padding: 0; white-space:nowrap">
        We never win because you only believe in science!
    </td>
</tr>
```

On CSS,this rule was added:

```
div,p,a,li,td {
-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
-moz-text-size-adjust: none;
-ms-text-size-adjust: none;
text-size-adjust: none;}
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: deleting the `!important`  seems to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have `font-family:` twice!

Hope that helps!

Comment: I changed it, but still does not appear to fix the problem on gmail.

Comment: Ok, I can't think of anything, I will remove my post.